# Flutter - How to parse data from a website to a list view

Tags: android, html, ios, dart, flutter

I'm looking for help with my test app to provide a news feed that parses it's data from a website, namely **[VMoneyNews](https://www.virtualmoneysnews.com/category/bitcoin-news/)** **(I have their permission to use their data)**.

I aim for this to parse the `article title`, `main article text` and `article image` of each article in the `Bitcoin News` category for implementation into the `listView`, in this case a horizontal `listViewRow`.

Please **don't** include the header text in bold at the top of each article, or the link to similar articles.

Could someone please provide this code for me? I assume this will be using the HTML dependency but I just don't know where to start implementing this feature.

Thank you.

Comment: please don't say "I'll be paying a 50 rep reward within 24hrs of my question being answered." if anyone want to help you he would do that without this

Comment: Okay I’ll bear this in mind and edit my question, it’s just that I really need this answered ASAP.

Comment: https://medium.com/@ayushpguptaapg/website-scraping-with-dart-flutter-56db60033d49

Answer (score 16, accepted):

i created a full application that shows how to parse HTML and extract data from it you can [find it here](https://github.com/Rahiche/flutter_jobs_app) but the idea is simple :

1.import this 3 libraries for html parsing

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:html/parser.dart' as parser;
import 'package:html/dom.dart' as dom;
```

2.get the data from the page you want

```
Future<List<String>> getData() async { 
  http.Response response = await http.get('website');
}
```

3.extract the data from the website

```
dom.Document document = parser.parse(response.body);
```

4. depend on your need let's say you want to get all element with the article tag

```
document.getElementsByTagName('article')
```

and then you can iterate throw all article using for-each and do the same to get the data inside the article . also consider making a model class for the article so you can mangle that easily later on

Comment: This is great, I’ll test this and get back to you on it on the 16th of August. (Late in my country)

Comment: Thank you, this helped a bunch :)

Comment: Is there anyway I could contact you about this? Might be too lengthy for stack unless I open a new question so could I email you about this? Just want to ask about migrating some of your code into my project. Thanks

Comment: you can contact me on twitter you will find the link in mu profile

Comment: Thank you, I will try and contact you in the next hour.

Comment: Please reply to my tweet from “jakeantbailey”

Comment: is there any batter way to do that..like any package

Answer (score 3):

Web Scraping in dart is easy now!
Just check [web_scraper](https://pub.dev/packages/web_scraper) package on pub.

Using this package you can **scrape** the website's HTML tags data into simple lists & maps.

You can find a similar [example](https://github.com/tusharojha/web_scraper/tree/master/example) in its repository.

Answer (score 2):

I think a clean solution is to do those stuff on the backend if possible , if you use `nodejs` as your backend , you may think of `casperJs` or `phantomJs` , to parse the html `DOM` and extract data and return a clean `json` data to the mobile app .

Comment: Will this be implemented on server side?

Comment: yes this wil be done on server side , it can be made in mobile somehow bit it needs a lot of hardware resources .